# Two different versions of Schrödinger's equation - are they equivalent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, differentiation, notation

For simplicity, let's look at the case of one particle in one dimension. We usually think of the wave function as a function
\begin{align}
\Psi\colon\mathbb R\times[0,\infty[&\to\mathbb C\\
(x,t)&\mapsto\Psi(x,t)
\end{align}
and Schrödinger's equation has the form
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\mathrm{i}\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi=\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x{}^2}+V\right)\Psi\quad
\end{equation}

On the other hand, [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) allows us to think of the wave function as a function of time:
\begin{align}
\psi\colon[0,\infty[&\to L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})
\end{align}
In other words, $\psi(t)$ is the function defined by $(\psi(t))(x)=\Psi(x,t)$ - the particle's wave function at the time $t$.
That being said, the following equation makes sense:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\mathrm{i}\hbar\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\psi=\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x{}^2}+V\right)\psi
\end{equation}
Please notice that I replaced the partial derivatives by total derivatives.

**Q**: Are both equations - (1) and (2) - valid? Are they equivalent?

Comment: Your two equations / interpretations seem to be completely equivalent mathematically, why would you think they're not? I assume the first interpretation is augmented with the square integrability condition.

Comment: The existence of the standard $t$-derivative is a $x$-pointwise condition, whereas the derivative in the sense of $L^2$ space is $x$-global (integral) condition.They are quite independent from each other. The former does not have global implications whereas the latter sees the functions up to zero $x$- measure sets. However a link exists arising from some results in the $L^p$ convergence theory.  What matters in QM is the second notion  due to its connection with the Stone theorem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two approaches are different and inequivalent. The physically correct one is the latter since the Schroedinger equation is nothing but the application of the **Stone theorem** to the time evolution and there the relevant topology to compute derivatives is the Hilbert space one. In other words, the S. equation arises by taking a suitable  type of $t$ derivative on both sides of the identity
$$\psi_t = e^{-itH/\hbar} \psi_0\:.$$
This type of derivative is the one described below in (1) which is used in the said theorem eventually leading to the wanted equation
$$i\hbar \dot{\psi}_t =  H \psi_t\:.$$
The other notion of $t$-derivative, relying on standard calculus only,  is however interesting from the viewpoint of PDE theory.

The correct notion of $t$-derivative in QM  is therefore  the one, I indicate by $\dot{\psi}_t$,  in the $L^2$ space performed with respect to the norm of that space:

$$\left|\left|\dot{\psi}_t - \frac{\psi_{t+h}-\psi_t}{h}\right|\right|_{L^2(\mathbb{R})} \to 0 \quad \mbox{for}\quad h\to 0\:.\tag{1}$$
In integral terms
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\dot{\psi}_t(x) - \frac{\psi_{t+h}(x)-\psi_t(x)}{h} \right|^2 dx \to 0 \quad \mbox{for}\quad h\to 0\:.$$

The existence of the standard $t$-derivative $\partial_t \psi_t(x)$ is a $x$-pointwise condition, whereas the derivative $\dot{\psi}_t$ in the sense of $L^2$ space is $x$-global (integral) condition.They are quite independent from each other. The former does not have global implications whereas the latter sees the functions up to zero $x$-measure sets.

However if $t \mapsto \psi_t$ admits $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ $t$-derivative $\dot{\psi}_t$ and, simultaneously, $(t,x) \mapsto \psi_t(x)$ also admits standard partial $t$ derivative $\partial_t\psi_t(x)$, then the two derivatives coincide for almost  all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ at the given $t$.

**PROOF** Suppose that $\partial_t\psi_t(x)$ exists for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and the said $t$. Suppose that also
$\frac{d}{dt}_{L^2}\psi_t =: \dot{\psi}_t \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ exists as in (1). Hence, if $h\to 0$,
$$\frac{\psi_{t+h}-\psi_t}{h} \to \dot{\psi}_t \quad \mbox{in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ sense as in (1)}\:.$$
Due to a known theorem of $L^p$ convergence, there is a sequence $h_n \to 0$ such that, as $n\to +\infty$,
$$\frac{\psi_{t+h_n}(x)-\psi_t(x)}{h_n} \to \dot{\psi}_t(x) \quad \mbox{for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$}\:.$$
However the existence of $\partial_t\psi_t(x)$ requires
$$\frac{\psi_{t+h_n}(x)-\psi_t(x)}{h_n} \to \partial_t\psi_t(x) \quad \mbox{for  all $x \in \mathbb{R}$}\:.$$
In summary
$$\partial_t\psi_t(x) = \dot{\psi}_t(x) \quad \mbox{for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.}$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115959/discussion-on-answer-by-valter-moretti-two-different-ways-to-read-schrodinger).

Comment: In other words: If $\dot{\psi}_t\in L^2$ and $\partial_t\Psi(\,\cdot\,,t)$ exist, then $\partial_t\Psi(\,\cdot\,,t)$ is square integrable (that is, $\partial_t\Psi(\,\cdot\,,t)\in\mathcal L^2$) and its equivalence class is $\dot{\psi}_t$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Okay, this means that we have proven $\left[\mathrm{i}\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi(\,\cdot\,,t)\right]=\mathrm{i}\hbar\dot{\psi}_t$. My guess would be that we can also prove
$\left[\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\Psi+V\Psi\right)(\,\cdot\,,t)\right]=H\psi_t$. If this is true, the second Schrödinger equation follows from the first one.

Comment: Yes, it is true also that. In this case you can handle the S. equation as a standard PDE.

Comment: However the second equation is nothing but the definition of H and it is true independently from the identity of the two types of derivatives.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the confirmation :)